# How to make seaborn.heatmap larger (normal size)?

Tags: python, heatmap, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I displayed plot with the following command in jupyter notebook:

```
sns.heatmap(pcts, annot=True, linewidth=.1, vmax=99, fmt='.1f', cmap='YlOrRd', square=True, cbar=False)
plt.yticks(list(reversed(range(len(indices)))), ['Index '+str(x) for x in indices], rotation='horizontal')
plt.title('Percentile ranks of\nsamples\' category spending');
```

and got the following picture

[image: heatmap with squares too small]

i.e. squares appear unacceptably small.

How can I make them larger?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Before using `heatmap()`, call [`matplotlib.pyplot.figure()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) with the `figsize` parameter to set the size of the figure. For example:

```
pyplot.figure(figsize=(10, 16))
sns.heatmap(...)
```

The two elements of the tuple passed to `figsize` are the desired width and height of the figure in inches. Then when you make the heatmap, it will stretch to fill the available space given that size. You may have to do a bit of experimentation to determine what size looks best.

Comment: What if seaborn plot size is then bigger than Jupyter Notebook cell width? Can it be made scrollable?

Answer (score 6):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

sns.heatmap(df)
```